# Override geolocation using robot framework and seleniumlib

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I've trying to override geolocation using robot + seleniumLib, all docs mention this python code, using cdp commands, but how do i import this code in this case?
I read something about using the keyword "Create Webdriver", but really dont know how it works.
Can anyone help me with this?

.py and .robot file are in same folder.

.robot file

```
***Settings***
Library             SeleniumLibrary
Library             geo.py

Suite Teardown      End    
***Variables***

***Test Cases***
Test Location
    Should appear the overrided location


***Keywords***
End
    Close All Browsers

Should appear the overrided location
    Open Browser                        https://browserleaks.com/geo       Chrome 
    Wait Until Page Contains            HTML5 Geolocation API
    Scroll Element Into View            xpath://*[@id="footer"]     
    Page Should Not Contain Element     xpath://*[@alt="BR"]    #flag img from my current country location
    Sleep                               5
    Close Browser
```

.py file

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

def geoLocation_Test():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    Map_coordinates = dict({
        "latitude": 41.8781,
        "longitude": -87.6298,
        "accuracy": 100
        })
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", Map_coordinates)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create a new instance of the browser. You can get SeleniumLibrary's instance of the driver through the `driver` attribute of the library.

Here's how to define a function to set the geolocation in chrome:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def set_geolocation(latitude, longitude, accuracy=100):
    map_coordinates = {
        "latitude": float(latitude),
        "longitude": float(longitude),
        "accuracy": int(accuracy),
    }
    selib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SeleniumLibrary")
    selib.driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", map_coordinates)
```

The following test passes, showing the location to be Chicago, IL even though that's not my physical location nor the location of my VPN connection.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  geo.py
Library  SeleniumLibrary

Suite Setup     open browser  about:blank  chrome
Suite Teardown  close browser

*** Test Cases ***
Geolocation Example
    [Setup]  set geolocation  41.8781  -87.6298  100

    Go to  https://my-location.org

    Element should contain  id=latitude   41.8781
    Element should contain  id=longitude  -87.6298

    capture page screenshot
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks dude, ive lost weeks on this, i dont even know how to thanks... Didnt find any explicit exemple like this, amazing <3